# should FFL where clause allow referring to previous variable?

Tags: where-clause, ffl, anura

So, in Frogatto Formula Language we can have a where clause with multiple assignments, like where a = yadda, b = foo

However I can't refer to `a` in the assignment of `b` ?

I was hoping to simplify by breaking it into steps, `where a = ..., b = ...(refers to var a)...`

Note: it doesn't seem to work in `where b,a` order either:

```
EVALUATING: [a,b] where b=a+1, a=1
ASSERTION FAILED: Unknown symbol 'a'
[a,b] where b=a+1, a=1
              ^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ladder of where clauses, like this:

`[a,b] where b = a+1 where a = 1`

Comment: Ok, that works. Do you think the a=1, b=a+1 syntax should be supported in a future version?

Comment: I think we might end up supporting that. It would certainly alleviate some confusion such as yours.

Comment: I would recommend newbies to tend to ladders of `where` as much as possible instead of parallel `where` variables, so this way every comma is clearly a separation between two elements in the upmost scope. A parallel `where` clause introduces complexity so a comma could be inside a `where` scope, and the engine could have some problems to know if a comma ends a `where` clause or instead ends the FFL element for which that `where` clause is defining additional variables.